# Is the Stack Overflow coffee cup coded in Java?

Tags: discussion, 10m-questions-milestone

I recently received this lovely coffee mug as part of the 10M questions celebration.

The side of the mug looks like this:

[image]

```
if(owner.isCoding()
&& mug.isEmpty())
{mug.fill('coffee');}
```

I'm not a Java programmer, but I'm [guessing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) this is Java syntax and that this is something of a pun given that "Java" is a nickname for coffee, at least in dated American slang.

However, given that we don't see the class declarations for `owner` and `mug`, I'm guessing it could also be C++; perhaps it's deliberately ambiguous.

I like the mug but I sort of feel like a poseur carrying it around since I don't use either of these languages.  So I would appreciate some info, particularly if there's an inside joke I'm not getting.  Is there any significance in brackets being on the same line instead of:

```
if( owner.isCoding()
    && mug.isEmpty() ){
  mug.fill('coffee');
}
```

(I understand there may be a line limit for the printable area on the mug.)

Comment: It is pseudo-code in a language with C-derived syntax. If you're worried about being a poseur, imagine how I feel, drinking *tea* out of this 'coffee' mug.

Comment: Cross-site dupe. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138755/1288

Comment: I'm a little bit more worried about filling your mug with a string, rather than an instance of a coffee object. This might be a case of [string obsession](http://cyrille.martraire.com/2010/01/the-string-obsession-anti-pattern/).

Comment: It might not be Java on the outside, but it could very well be CoffeeScript on the inside ;)

Comment: clearly it's written in jQuery.

Comment: @Cody me too. But the worst part is, none of my co-workers appreciate it because they all don't care about SO. :-(

Comment: It wasn't ever going to be Java since Java doesn't have strings with single quotes :(

Comment: It's valid JavaScript. But also, it's 'writing on a coffee mug'...or in other terms 'script written on java'...javascript!

Comment: Imho it's not **java**. If it's java it should enclose `mug.fill('coffe')` with `try { } catch (CupOverflowException e) {}` or declare `throws CupOverflowException` on the method that runs the code :). Though I would love to have this cup and drink coffee from it in front of my colleagues :D.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 How in the world did you get this cup and I don't :-(

Comment: It would be super cool if we got a coffee mug with the algorithm printed in our most answered language.  Call it the 'buzzbuzz' algorithm 8-)

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Congratulations on receiving your swag!

It is definitely not Java, as Java uses [double quotes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) for string literals (single quotes are used for character literals). The same holds for [C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t.aspx). It could be Java*Script*, though.

Code snippets (in tutorials, or in StackOverflow questions) don't always show the declarations, because they can be derived from the context. And they're probably too boring to print on a mug.

While the mug itself is not coded in Java, it can definitely be filled with [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_coffee).

Comment: Could also be Groovy, though it wouldn't be idiomatic on the property accesses.

Comment: And here I was thinking 'java' was slang for coffee everywhere. Didn't even realize it was an actual place.

Comment: It can't be Javascript, because surely it would have more jQuery.

Comment: @Stryner Depends if there's any [vanilla](http://vanilla-js.com/) flavour.

Comment: It's SCRIPT written on a cup of JAVA. JAVASCRIPT!!!

Answer (score 143):

It's not Java, it's our own language that we developed called Nij. And, I regret to inform you that we're recalling all mugs due to consumer safety concerns.

As you note, the mug has this line of code:

```
if(owner.isCoding()
```

The more experienced of you will notice, *no check is done* to ensure `owner` is the expected type. While no incidents have been reported, the following scenarios *might* result in undefined mug behavior:

- Owner changing, or non-owner use of mug
- Existential difficulties of owner

We urge everyone to drink with extreme caution while we work this out.

Comment: https://media.giphy.com/media/ALBfFB6gP1evu/giphy-facebook_s.jpg ?

Comment: Must resist urge to create [[tag:nij]] on SO

Comment: So it is in fact a misprint? Then I wouldn't return it (if I had one) - misprints are certain to become valuable collector's items.

Comment: They also have another serious issue: That if statement should be a while loop. As it's currently written, the mug will only be filled once, which is _very_, _very_ bad :-)

Comment: Surely worse than that - what if the owner is no longer coding because they have **Run out of Coffee!** they're unable to concentrate on coding but their mug isn't giving them more coffee!

Comment: Surely even worse than that - what if the owner never actually started coding because there was no coffee in the mug to begin with ?! (@Ian)

Comment: @JonasCz Should be a `do...while`. Regardless, there is clearly need for optimization here.

Comment: @isUserAGoat do fill while coding or do coding while fill ?

Comment: Coffee first @tak3shi , which will handle the bug the JonasCz brought up. And add in an `if` to ensure coding. Depending on how important the project is, possibly throw an exception if  `mug.isFull && owner.isSlacking`.

Comment: @isUserAGoat, [Unfortunately Nij does not have support for do..while loops](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MKVvR.png).., so that's a moot point anyhow :-)

Comment: So what you're saying is if we continue to use this mug before it's patched, we might get a bug in our coffee? Eww, gross!

Comment: Let´s swap owner with mug in the code. Mug is better in writing Nij code and the owner knows how to fill a mug with coffee.

Comment: May we expect a patch or a service pack in 6-8 weeks?

Comment: We also have to see what happens when we put something _other_ than coffee in these things. We're going to be experimenting with gravy and Jello shortly.

Comment: I dont think, that it will be possible to patch this mug without an upgrade. You will need something bigger to implement all the required changes. We should think about extending this mug with another one. I hope that Nij has extension support?

Comment: Is the word "nij" some kind of in-joke that I'm missing?

Comment: No overflow checks either.  C'mon people did you forget where you work?

Comment: Having obsessed with SCP recently, I'd say this could be proposed as "coder's coffee mug"... definitely not Safe.

Comment: @KyleStrand `"Jin Yang".Explode(0).Reverse();` and that's totally legal in Nij.

Comment: Calling a method on an object that could possibly be `null`? If someone fills that cup with scalding coffee while it does not yet have an owner, the stack trace is going to blow the bottom out of the cup.

Comment: Also, Nij doesn't have assertions, but objects do have a built in `.PrayIsNot()` method. So if you want to patch your mug, `owner.PrayIsNot(null);` This feature is called "Prayer Abstraction" and it's not yet done, and is not guaranteed to return. So use at your own risk.

Comment: I assume that Nij is loosely typed considering you have to check that user is the expected type? I don't have to do that in Swift .

Answer (score 18):

magic strings are a questionable pattern,  I suggest returning an enum as in owner.beverageOfChoice.  Be that as it may, 'coffee' works for me.

Comment: Yep. There definitely needs to be a variant for tea drinkers. I want my mug to be filled with tea, Earl Grey, hot.

Answer (score 5):

It may very well be Java, depending on how long it took for you to receive the mug.

/runs and hides

Comment: My mug has been sitting on my table ever since I got one, and it hasn't run _once_ yet. You could be onto something.

Answer (score 4):

It is not Java, but if you execute the script twice in a row, it will overflow with Java.